# Windows 10 Command Prompt Stuck in Legacy Mode and Won't Start

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

Recently checked the "Use legacy console" option for cmd trying to fix font problems I was having and now launching it causes a 0xc0000142 error and I can't change it back as it won't save the changed setting.

Answer (score 1):

That "legacy console" option should only be available on a shortcut to cmd.exe, not on cmd.exe itself. So hopefully something is wrong with your shortcut and not with the actual cmd.exe. Try browsing to c:\windows\system32 (or whatever your system dir is), then running cmd.exe directly from there. Alternatively, press WIN+R and run **c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe** directly.

If that works like normal, then just delete the existing shortcut that's giving you the problems and create a new shortcut, that should fix it.

If running cmd.exe directly also doesn't work like normal, here are some other ideas:

- update your windows updates
- try system restore to the most recent point before this problem appeared
- try running cmd.exe in safe mode
- boot to Windows 10 command prompt and run sfc to check your system files
- if you haven't upgraded yet, you could try and grab the Anniversary Update

Good luck.